# Getting Jekyll to turn images supplied in a YAML file into a background slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll

I have `cover.yml`, with the following:

```
imagelist:
    - image: static/images/covers/doctor.jpeg
    - image: static/images/covers/freelancer.jpeg
    - image: static/images/covers/misc.jpeg
```

I can't figure out how to switch through this using Jekyll. I have managed to with Hugo, but can't replicate it with Jekyll.

```html
<div class="bgImage">
    {{ if eq (printf "%T" $cover.images) "string"}}
      <div class="coverImage" style="background-image: url('{{$baseUrl}}images/covers/{{ $cover.images }}')"></div>
    {{ end }}
    {{ if eq (printf "%T" $cover.images) "[]interface {}" }}
      {{ if lt (len $cover.images) 2}}
        <div class="coverImageStatic" style="background-image: url('{{$baseUrl}}images/covers/{{ index $cover.images 0 }}')"></div>
      {{ else }}
        {{ range $cover.images }}<div class="coverImage" style="background-image: url('{{$baseUrl}}images/covers/{{ . }}')"></div>
        {{ end }}
      {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
  </div>
```

I have this for some for some of the CSS:

```
{{ if eq (printf "%T" $cover.images) "[]interface {}" }}
    {{ if gt (len $cover.images) 1 }}
      .cover .bgImage div.coverImage{
        height: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        position: absolute;
        animation: slide {{mul (len $cover.images) 5 }}s infinite;
        opacity: 0;
      }

      {{ range $index, $element := $cover.images }}
        {{ if eq (add $index 1) (len $cover.images) }}

        {{ else }}
        .bgImage > div.coverImage:nth-child({{add $index 2}}) {
          animation-delay: {{mul (add $index 1) 5}}s;
        }
        {{ end }}
      {{ end }}

      @keyframes slide {
        10% {
          opacity: 1;
        }
        20% {
          opacity: 1;
        }
        90% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
          transform: scale(1.1);
        }
      }
    {{ end }}

  {{ end }}
```

I am thinking that I should be able to check how many items are in `imagelist`, and then iterate through the `{% for item in site.data.cover %}` like I do with the navbar. However, not really sure how to implement this.

Any ideas?